# The function returns different answers for the same given

Tags: python, python-3.x

The required is a function that takes a string and returns the most repeated character in it without considering the punctuations, white spaces and numbers, it also treats `"A" == "a"`, if the string has equally repeated characters it returns the letter which comes first in the Latin alphabet.

Here is the function given the examples, I've commented it for more clarification

```
def checkio(text):
    # any char
    result = "a"
    # iterating through small chars
    for i in text.lower():
        # iterating through lowercase letters only and not considering punctuation, white spaces and letters
    if i in string.ascii_lowercase:
        # If i is repeated more than the result
        if text.count(i) > text.count(result):
            result = i
        # in case the letters are equal in repeated the same time
        elif text.count(i) == text.count(result):
            # returning according to the letter which comes first in the 
              Latin alphabet
            if string.ascii_lowercase.find(i) < string.ascii_lowercase.find(result):
                result = i
    return result

print(checkio("Hello World!"))
print(checkio("How do you do?"))
print(checkio("One"))
print(checkio("Oops!"))
print(checkio("abe"))
print(checkio("a" * 9000 + "b" * 1000))

# Here is the problem
print(checkio("AAaooo!!!!")) # returns o
print(checkio("aaaooo!!!!")) # returns a --> the right solution!
```

Comment: You're only looping over lowercased string, for `.count()` you're still using the original string.

Comment: Don't you have an indentitation issue after first `for` in your code?

Comment: The indentation issue is just because I wrote it wrong here, but there is no issue in my editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When to execute text.count(i) for "AAaooo!!!!", it does the following: A : count = 2 a : count = 1 o : count = 3 .... and so on.

Hence, before counting the characters, you need to convert the entire string to lower case. That will solve your issue.

```
def checkio(text):
    # any char
    result = "a"
    # iterating through small chars
    for i in text.lower():
        # iterating through lowercase letters only and not considering punctuation, white spaces and letters
      if i in string.ascii_lowercase:
          # If i is repeated more than the result
          if text.lower().count(i) > text.lower().count(result):
              result = i
          # in case the letters are equal in repeated the same time
          elif text.lower().count(i) == text.lower().count(result):
              # returning according to the letter which comes first in the Latin alphabet
              if string.ascii_lowercase.find(i) < string.ascii_lowercase.find(result):
                  result = i
    return result


print(checkio("AAaooo!!!!")) # returns a
print(checkio("aaaooo!!!!")) # returns a
```

Comment: Strange! So what is the benefit of iterating through the lower case from the beginning if I have to call .lower() again, They are already lower cases!!

Comment: You call to text.lower() does not update the 'text'. To be able to call the lower() method only once, you should save the result to some other variable like 'new_text = text.lower()'. Then you can do all your operations on new_text without having to call lower() method again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Your calls to `text.count` don't call `lower()` first.  At the top of the function, you should call `text = text.lower()`.  Then your `text.count` calls will work on the same normalized, lowercase characters that your iterator does.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.